# file upload in selenium webdriver using Autoit in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, autoit-c#-wrapper

I have a scenario where I need to upload excel file using selenium. For this I am using Autoit(as a nuget package to Visual studio). When I use below code i am able to upload file to my application but I have to use file path as my active directory but not my local machine.

```
AutoItX.WinWaitActive("Open");
AutoItX.ControlFocus("Open", "", "Edit1");
AutoItX.ControlSetText("Open", "", "Edit1", "D:\\Perseus\\V2-ModelUpdate.xlsm");
AutoItX.ControlClick("Open", "", "Button1");
```

My requirement is...when I run my selenium script the excel file should be picked from TFS's active directory but not my local machine as we are integrating with CI. Once the Build is successful the the selenium script should be pass. please help me here.

Answer (score 1):

This is for C#/ c Sharp
First you need to click on the select file button to upload image
Then use the following code :

```
AutoItX3 autoIt = new AutoItX3();
autoIt.WinActivate("Open"); // Window name to select a file 
autoIt.Send(@"C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\at.png"); // file path 
autoIt.Send("{Enter}");`
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out AutoIt uses a different protocol as compared to Selenium and is not supported on BrowserStack Automate. So I used [`RemoteWebDriver`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html) instead of autoit for this requirement, and it is working fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
[TestFixture]
    public class FileUpload
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestMethod()
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://smallpdf.com/pdf-to-jpg");
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@class='l3tlg0-0 hrcxSS']")).Click();
            Thread.Sleep(4000);
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(@"C:\Users\Bhagya.HS\Documents.FileUpload.exe");
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).